# figuring out grid layout in % confused

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

I have been trying to understand this grid system that people have been using. At times kind of makes me feel dumb.

I understand that if you use a 12 grid system with no margins. That column 12 will be 100%, and whereas 1 column will be approx 8.33333%.

I have been looking at some grid systems and the onepcss grid and I am confused a little bit. I know that 1% is left over since he/she is stating a full width grid is 99%. They use margins of 3% but one column is = to 5.5% but if I do the math 100/12 = 8.33333% - 3% (for the margin) = 5.3333%

I posted an example below of their grids. I am trying to use basic math to figure out what one column is what am I doing wrong?

```
.col1 { width: 5.5%; }
.col2 { width: 14%; }
.col3 { width: 22.5%; }
.col4 { width: 31%; }
.col5 { width: 39.5%; }
.col6 { width: 48%; }
.col7 { width: 56.5%; }
.col8 { width: 65%; }
.col9 { width: 73.5%; }
.col10 { width: 82%; }
.col11 { width: 90.5%; }
.col12 { width: 99%; margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Can I recommend you look into bootstrap 3.0 it does all of this a lot lot easier.  More importantly it looks like you are using width as a cumulative number...it is not.

Comment: There's a lot more to a grid system than just the width.  If the system you're using isn't floating the containers then the 1% may be to take into account the whitespace between `inline-block` elements, or it would be for padding on the `container` element.  You'll need to include more information if you want a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a 12 column grid, there are 11 gutters. So the gutter width (33%) has to be subtracted from the total width (99%). If each gutter is 3% then a single column is:

(99 - 33) / 12 = 5.5

Then, multiple columns are the columns added together plus the gutters they "absorb". So a three column is:

5.5 + 5.5 + 5.5 + 3 + 3 = 22.5

(three column widths plus two gutter widths), visually:

```
┌─────── 22.5 ────────┐
| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5 |3| 5.5
```